# Multiple Timeouts using Twisted

Tags: python, twisted

I am sending 5 requests using the transport.write function. I wish to set a timeout for each of the 5 requests. The 5 requests are from the same Protocol Object. Is there any way for me to set a timeout using Twisted on each of the 5 requests?

Comment: What do you mean by "request"? What protocol are you using?

Comment: Please attach an http://sscce.org/.